# How to validate file types in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5

I am uploading a file on Laravel, and its validation doesn't seem to be working.

My controller code is as follows:

```
public function cv(Request $request) {
    if ($request->hasFile('cv')) {
        $file = $request->file('cv'); //i need this later to upload the file
        $rules= [
             'cv' => 'mimes:application/msword,text/plain,application/pdf,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'
        ];
        $x = $request->all();
        $validator=Validator::make($x, $rules);
        if ($validator->passes()){
            dd("Passes");
        }else{
            dd("fails");
        }
}}
```

My html code for my file is: `<input type='file' name='cv'><br>`

For some reason this code seems to fail, and the validator passes only if the file is a pdf. I only want the user to upload pdf files, doc files, docx files, amd text/plain files. When I attempt to upload a microsoft doc file, it fails. Could someone help me out, I am unsure what I am doing incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you reversed params

```
 $validator=Validator::make($x, $rules);
```

Comment: Ahh yes, apologies, I didn't pick up on that. Thanks! However, I am still unable to upload microsoft doc files.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this instead:

```
'cv' => 'mimes:pdf'
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-mimes

Answer (score 1):

As per [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-mimes), `mimetypes` should be used when specifying the mime types as you are, whereas `mimes` should be used to specify file extensions. HTH!